# JSon Type is not supported for deserialization of an array in C#

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I'm having an issue with some code that I've used previously and I'm sure I'm just being daft but I'm failing to find the reason for this.

The error I'm getting is "Type 'ScriptMain+Imports' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

```js
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]

public class ScriptMain : UserComponent

{

    string json;

    public override void PreExecute()

    {
        base.PreExecute();
        string url = this.Variables.apiurl; ;
        json = DownloadJson(url);
   }



    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()

    {

        JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Imports imports = (Imports)serialize.Deserialize(json, typeof(Imports));

        foreach (var contentType in imports.contents)

        {
            Output0Buffer.name = contentType.name;
        }

    }

    public static string DownloadJson(string downloadURL)

    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadString(downloadURL);
        }
    }

   
    public class Imports
    {
        public List<Contents> contents { get; set; }
    }


    public class Contents
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I feel that the only big difference is that on this Json import there is no Root identity, but I thought I'd resolved this using the public class Imports.

The values are coming from a URL, which unfortunately I can't provide due to an API key, but a sample of the results are below, however I'm currently only interested in the Name Value:

```html
[{"contentType":"SocialWeb","createDate":"2018-04-12 14:07:07","description":"Test Query 1","displayImgUrl":"","editDate":"2018-05-25 13:21:09","fhTwitterStatus":"OFF","fromDate":null,"languageFilters":["English"],"name":"Query1","sharing":"PUBLIC","status":"Active","timeInterval":"LAST_SIX_MONTHS","toDate":null,"topicId":"948015"},
{"contentType":"SocialWeb","createDate":"2017-09-29 10:53:21","description":"Test Query 2","displayImgUrl":"","editDate":"2017-10-18 03:06:41","fhTwitterStatus":"OFF","fromDate":"2017-06-18 02:25:13","languageFilters":["English"],"name":"Query2","sharing":"PUBLIC","status":"Standby","timeInterval":"OPEN_END","toDate":null,"topicId":"845703"},
{"contentType":"SocialWeb","createDate":"2016-11-24 00:53:50","description":"Test Query 3","displayImgUrl":"","editDate":"2016-11-24 00:54:31","fhTwitterStatus":"OFF","fromDate":"2016-11-01 00:00:00","languageFilters":["English"],"name":"Query3","sharing":"PUBLIC","status":"Standby","timeInterval":"OPEN_END","toDate":null,"topicId":"689969"},]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no Root Identity but several values available as listed below, however at the moment I'm only interested in the Name values.

Comment: editDate
 fhTwitterStatus
 fromDate
 languageFilters
 name
 sharing
 status
 timeInterval
 toDate
 topicId

Comment: Please update your question with the value of `json`.

Answer (score 0):

try with Microsoft Newtonsoft.Json
like

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";
```

then you write simply

```
Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

here  Movie is class it contains all keys from json

Comment: I think this is heading in the right direction, but the Json has multiple rows and I need to list each, my previous way works ok when the root is named, also I don't have any control over that as it's being provided via a third party API.